# There's no If statement built in with Endif statement in my PHP?

Tags: php, html

```php
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])); ?>
    <li href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <?php echo $_SESSION['fname'];?>
        <i class="fa-chevron-down" ></i>
    </li>       
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a href="a">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="a" class="logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<?php else ?>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\penat\register.php on line 75

Comment: '<?php endif; ?>
 </div>' my continue code

Comment: `..ION['id']));` should be `..ION['id'])):`

Comment: I think it's work but I'm not so sure because another error coming up from my database.php. btw thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong syntax for your `if else` statements

Instead you can try for

```
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])): ?>

            <li href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['fname'];?>
                <i class="fa-chevron-down" ></i>
            </li>       
        </ul>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="a">Profile</a></li>
             <li><a href="a" class="logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php else: ?>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```